# How to fix You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement a GAN, I get an error even though I have checked that I am passing values to the placeholder. I have tried a lot of the solutions but still unable to fix this. All suggestions appreciated.

[here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1T3PwlSQY0jLqhsAoI2k1glJ167BnHUt5?usp=sharing)

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you provide code directly in the question ?